# Unexpected Token } caused by a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html-table

Right now I'm trying to use a Javascript function to create a table inside of a div when I click on a picture. Am I able to define the created table to call upon a different function? (example below)

```
if (band == 'creed') {
   d('albumList').innerHTML = 
      "<table class='default'>"+
         "<td class='albumListC' id='mopCover'>"+
         "<img class='i' src='images/albums/myownprison.jpg'
               onclick='"+"createSongBar('mop');"+"'></td>"+
         "<td class='albumListC' id='hcCover'>"+
         "<img class='i' src='images/albums/humanclay.jpg'
               onclick='"+"createSongBar('hc');"+"'></td>"+
         "<td class='albumListC' id='wCover'>"+
         "<img class='i' src='images/albums/weathered.jpg'
               onclick='"+"createSongBar('w');"+"'></td>"+
         "<td class='albumListC' id='fcCover'>"+
         "<img class='i' src='images/albums/fullcircle.jpg'
               onclick='"+"createSongBar('fc');"+"'></td>"+
      "</table>";
}
```

The code excerpt comes from the function I want to run when I click on the second table with 4 cells.

My webpage shows a table with 3 cells at the top, and each of the cells, when clicked on, runs a function that creates another table below it with 4 cells. What I want is for another function to run when I click on each of the 4 new cells, but I get this error when I click on it: (the error points to the second line of my main page, which only has one item on it; the < html > tag).

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token }

Any suggestions as to what may be causing this problem? I omitted the rest of my program for simplicity and because everything else works without an issue until this point.

Comment: `onclick='"+"createSongBar('fc');"+"'` will render as `onclick='createSongBar('fc')'` - Note the double matching string delimiters.

Comment: Your string has a syntax error. Example `"<img class='i' src='images/albums/fullcircle.jpg'` has a return after it, making it an invalid string.

Comment: This is a horrible approach to creating a table.  Please consider something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17056770/778118).

Comment: Why don't you put it in the template file? I'll be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this. Build elements, add elements, control what happens. Also, don't use a table. Which you're using incorrectly because it has no `<tr>` instruction... so let's do this instead:

```
if (band == 'creed') {
  var e = d('albumList');
  // set up data row
  var row = document.createElement("div");
  row.setAttribute("class", "default");
  e.appendChild(row);
  // fill row for images
  var imageData = {
        'myownprison': 'mop',
        'humanclay': 'hc',
        'weathered': 'w',
        'fullcircle': 'fc'
      },
      block,
      img;
  // loop through each image name
  Object.keys(imageData).forEach(function(imgName) {
    block = document.createElement("div");
    block.setAttribute("class","albumListC");
    img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute("class","i");
    img.src = "images/albums/" + imgName + ".jpg";
    img.onclick = function(evt) {
      createSongBar(imageData[imgName]);
    };
    // sets up row{block{img}}, the iterates to the next
    block.appendChild(img);
    row.appendChild(block);
  });
}
```

Now we have some generic code we can work with and expand on. Also, because we're not generating "strings" but correct HTML elements, we know it'll just work. No mismatched `{` or `"`, etc.

And if you're using a particular framework, like jQuery, this code can be made a LOT shorter.

Comment: I appreciate all of that, but I'm just starting out with integrating JavaScript into HTML, so quite a bit of what you've got here is beyond my experience so far.

I'd take it, however, that spending more time learning how to do all you've written above properly would be better than trying to debug the apparent mess I've originally written?

Comment: @Frigd - Yes.  The code you've written is almost impossible to read and maintain.  Also... Java is **completely** different than JavaScript.  You are trying to integrate _JavaScript_ into html, not Java.

Comment: I did mean JavaScript, just shortened it to "Java" to type faster. My bad.

Comment: If you're just starting out, now is the perfect time to learn: we do not make HTML elements with strings. We use document.createElement() and use DOM insert/replace/modify/etc functions. To the web tutorials with you =)

Comment: @Frigd You should construct your dynamic html like this as far as possible, especially when you are trying to append such long strings. This will be easier to maintain, readable, less prone to issues like what you are facing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - A link to some good web tutorials might be good...

Comment: There's too many, really. A search engine will turn up loads (avoid w3schools, their material is so flawed it spawned w3fools.com). Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript, which covers it better than I can.